# AbstractControl doesn't contain async validation error after adding a timer

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular7

I'm creating a registration form with reactive forms where the customer has to insert an email address. I added an async validator to this control to check if the inserted email is already in use.

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  ...,
  emailGroup: this.formBuilder.group({
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email], uniqueEmailValidator(this.registerService)],
    confirmEmail: ['', [Validators.required]]
  }, { validator: emailMatcher }),
  ...
});
```

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="reg-email">E-mailadres</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="reg-email" formControlName="email" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': form.get('emailGroup.email').errors && (form.get('emailGroup.email').touched || isSubmitted)}">
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      <div *ngIf="form.get('emailGroup.email').errors?.required || form.get('emailGroup.email').errors?.email">
        Please insert a valid email
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="form.get('emailGroup.email').errors?.uniqueEmail">                
        This email is already in use
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Originally my async validator looks like this:

```
export function uniqueEmailValidator(registerService: RegisterService): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (c: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
        return registerService.getCustomersByEmail(c.value).pipe(
            map(customers => {
                return customers && customers.length > 0 ? { 'uniqueEmail': true } : null;
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Everything works correct until now. When I insert an existing email, I receive the error message 'this email is already in use'.

I noticed that this async validator was executed per inserted character and for performance reasons I want to avoid this. I decided to add a timer of 500ms and to only execute the async validation when there is no activity for 500ms. This changes my async validator to this:

```
export function uniqueEmailValidator(registerService: RegisterService): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (c: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
        return timer(500).pipe(
            map(x => {
                return registerService.getCustomersByEmail(c.value).pipe(
                    map(customers => {
                        return customers && customers.length > 0 ? { 'uniqueEmail': true } : null;
                    })
                );
            })
        );
    };
}
```

The validator does the job correctly and the email control is marked as invalid after the async validation. The issue is that my html does not display the error message 'This email is already in use' anymore. The error code 'uniqueEmail' is not added to the errors object of my control.

Can someone shed some light on this one? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed the exact same thing. So I did it little differently. I created an async validation method which returns the promise of validation error in case of error. So this method delays the call to the server for 500ms and if there is any change during the delay it cancels the previous timeout and starts the new one. So ultimately just one call be sent on the server if the user is typing. Have a look below.

Declare these two variables

```
validationDelay: any;
validateUniqueEmail: any;
```

Define the following async validation method. Remember I used instance var because I could not use `this` context in the promise. So dont be confused.

```
validateEmail( c: FormControl): Promise<{[key: string]: any}> {
const instance = this;
return new Promise(resolve => {
  if (instance.validationDelay) {
    clearTimeout(instance.validationDelay);
  }
  instance.validationDelay = setTimeout(() => {
   instance.registerService.getCustomersByEmail(c.value)
    .subscribe((customers) => {
      if (customers && customers.length > 0) {
        resolve({
          uniqueEmail: true
        });
      } else {
        resolve(null);
      }
    }, (err) => {
      resolve(null);
    });
  }, 500);
});
}
```

Now to use this async method. Init it in the following way

```
ngOnInit(): void {
 this.validateUniqueEmail = (control: FormControl) => {
  return this.validateEmail(control);
 };
}
```

Use this `validateUniqueEmail` in your `FormControl`

`email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email], this.validateUniqueEmail]`